# Script php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073740791

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Why is it throwing an error? What can I do to debug the issue?

Composer version 1.7.2 2018-08-16 16:57:12
Running on Windows 10.

I can run php artisan package:discover manually without issue. I'm not sure what the number at the end means. I ran this with composer update -vvv

```
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> post-autoload-dump: Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> post-autoload-dump: php artisan package:discover
Executing command (CWD): php artisan package:discover
Script php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code -1073740791
```

Comment: are you running composer under windows ? it might be a hardware error code

Comment: I am. I'll keep looking. It doesn't happen every time with other projects. One specific project, it always happens. I'll have to check another computer to see if it happens there with this same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the issue was due to having multiple versions of php and copy and paste. 
Likely the version of php that composer was using had the extension folder point to a different version's extension folder.

If I had properly installed the different versions, I would not have gotten the issue.

Removal of all unused php versions and the reinstall of composer has fixed this issue.